# Change Validation Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a situation where the validation function I want to use depends on a choice that the user made earlier in the form. The page loads with a default validator, like so.

```
CustomValidator cv = new CustomValidator();
cv.ErrorMessage = "You must learn to follow instructions.";
cv.ControlToValidate = "myTextBox";
cv.EnableClientScript = true;
cv.CssClass = "Validator";
cv.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(cv_TextValidator);
cv.ClientValidationFunction = "textValidate";
u.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(cv);
```

When the user makes choice X, something like `timeInterval_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` is called. When they make that choice, I need to swap out the validation that is attached to some of my controls. In pseudo-code, I need something like this:

```
if user chose the first option {
    myControl.clientValidation = "textValidate";
    myControl.serverValidation = "cv_TextValidator";
} else {
    myControl.clientValidation = "alternateTextValidate";
    myControl.serverValidation = "cv_AlternateTextValidator";
}
```

**How can I swap out validation functions in code-behind?**

I know this can be accomplished with an if-else block inside of a single validation function. It could also be accomplished by hiding and showing other boxes that already have alternate validation attached. "If-else validation" and "hiding things" seem like non-elegant ways to solve the problem. I would rather rewire my functions to the proper ones.

Comment: You may associate this with "hiding things", but if not you could setup both validators on the control initially.  Instead of hiding/showing text boxes with different validation you can turn on/off the validators themselves.  It's not the most "elegant" way but it's a common strategy we use when having conditional validation.

Comment: @macoms01 For some reason, flipping validators on and off seems more acceptable than making textboxes visible or invisible. Maybe because you said it was a common strategy, I feel a little better about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClientValidationFunction is a string, so just change it to whatever you want like so:

```
if (SomeDDL.SelectedValue == "A")
   cv.ClientValidationFunction = "ValidateA";
else
   cv.ClientValidationFunction = "ValidateB";
```

It may not be tracked in ViewState, so you may have to set it on every postback to the server, in the Page_load or similar event (most likely PreRender or before).

For the other, simply attach to the correct handler:

```
if (SomeDDL.SelectedValue == "A")
   cv.ServerValidate += cv_FirstHandler;
else
   cv.ServerValidate += cv_SecondHandler;
```

For that, you'd have to do it on every postback too, and always do it from code, not markup.

Comment: I don't know what made you think this was going to happen client-side. The question clearly says **in code behind**. Also,  you said _"Swap the client validation function"_ which is precisely what I am asking how to do!

Comment: Corrected above, for the server code behind approach.  Thanks.